# Collect values in a list

Tags: racket

Is there a function that can give me a list of values returned by a function?

e.g. `(values->list (values 1 2 3))` resulting in `(list 1 2 3)`

If there isn't, is it possible to write such a function in racket which works for any number of values?

If this is not possible, is it by design?

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of multiple values is that the result should not be consed and use extra memory for wrapping the values. Anyway, here is what you want as a special form:

```
#lang racket
(require br/list)

(values->list (values 1 2 3)) 
; ==> (1 2 3)
```

If it doesn't work. Open `File` > `Package Manager`, choose the tab `Available from Catalog` and press the "Update package list" and then search "beautiful-racket". Select the result with that name and press `Install`. When it's finished you can close and press `Run` and it should work.

If you right click on `value->list` and choose "Open defining file" you'll see how it is made:

```
(define-macro values->list EXPR)
  #'(call-with-values (λ () EXPR) list))
```

Here is the same in vanilla Scheme from R5RS:

```
(define-syntax values->list
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ EXPR) (call-with-values (λ () EXPR) list))))
```

A function cannot implement this as it is the expression that returns multiple values and an argument slot in a function can only receive one value.